# Program crashes after checking index at array

Tags: c++, windows, memory

Please note: I am not sure if this fits here, if not, please move to the proper forum.

So I have a progrmam that tries to solve th Traveling Salesman Problem, TSP for short.

My code seems to run fine until I try to use 33810 cities, in which the program crashes after trying to access the position costs[69378120], it simply stops responding and end soon after.

I am trying the folowing code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <malloc.h>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <vector>
  #include <limits>

  using namespace std;

  typedef long long int itype;


  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    itype n;
    ifstream fenter;
  fenter.open(argv[1]);
  ofstream fexit;
  fexit.open(argv[2]);
  fenter>> n;
  double *x;
  double *y;
  x = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
  y = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
    cout<<"N : "<<n<<endl;
  for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
    fenter>> x[p] >> y[p];
  }
  fenter.close();

  int *costs;
  costs = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(n*n));
  for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
    for (int v = u+1; v < n; v++) {
      itype cost = floor(sqrt(pow(x[u] - x[v], 2) + pow(y[u] - y[v], 2)));
      cout<<"U: "<<u<<"   V: "<<v<<"    COST: "<<cost<<endl;
      costs[u*n + v] = cost;
      cout<<"POS (u*n + v): "<<(u*n + v)<<endl;
      cout<<"POS (v*n + u): "<<(v*n + u)<<endl;
      costs[v*n + u] = cost;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

According with some verifications, the cost array should use 9.14493GB, but Windows only gives 0.277497GB. Then after triying to read costs[69378120], it closes.
For now, I not worried about the efficiency, nor the solution to the TSP, just need to fix this issue. Any clues?

---UPDATE---
Following the sugestions I tried changing a few things. the result is the code below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int n;
ifstream entrada;
entrada.open(argv[1]);
ofstream saida;
saida.open(argv[2]);
entrada >> n;
vector<double> x(n);
vector<double> y(n);

for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
    entrada >> x[p] >> y[p];
}
entrada.close();

vector<itype> costs(n*n);
if(costs == NULL){ cout << "Sem memória!" << endl; return -1;}


for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
for (int v = u+1; v < n; v++) {
    itype cost = floor(sqrt(pow(x[u] - x[v], 2) + pow(y[u] - y[v], 2)));
  costs[u*n + v] = cost;
  costs[v*n + u] = cost;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem still persists

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222500/discussion-on-question-by-fernando-program-crashes-after-checking-index-at-array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compiling in 32-bit size_t is 32 bit and then

```
1143116100*4
```

is larger than the largest 32-bit number hence int overrun.

Compiling in 64-bit

```
size_t siz = 1143116100;
std::vector<long long> big(siz);
std::cout << big.size() << ", " << big.max_size() << std::endl;
```

which prints

```
1143116100, 2305843009213693951
```

if I change it to

```
size_t siz = 1024*1143116100;
```

I get a bad_alloc as my swap disk is not big enough for that.

Comment: It was indeed the problem with x32 and x64, i changed to Visual Studio complied for x64 and it seems to solve the problem,
Thanks to all that pointed that out.